# Change binding value in custom template trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml

How I can change binded property in custom template?

Button with Path Fill which is binded to Foreground of button:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource CustomButtonStyle}"Foreground="White" >
   <Path Data="PATH_DATA" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" ></Path>
</Button>
```

Here is custom style with override template:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#d5113f"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">    
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#d5113f"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

But changing Foregroud in trigger

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#d5113f"/>
```

will do nothing

Comment: remove `Foreground="White" `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you set `Foreground` to a fixed value, according to [Dependency Property Setting Precedence List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing), your style trigger will not override this value. You need to bring `Foreground` set into `Style` as another setter like this:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
   ...
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks! I miss this simple thing.